# Can JavaScript load raw bytes to use in HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Say I had a URL like

```
http://my.website.com/myfile.raw
```

and this file it points to was just raw bytes, representing an intensity image. Is it possible to grab this data and read the bytes in JavaScript? And then using it with HTML5 canvas (e.g. `putImageData`) to draw an image?

Or is there some other way to do this in the browser without Java or Flash?

Answer (score 1):

maybe

```
function draw() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
      ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
      imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height)
      //now you can do something with imageData...
    }
    img.src = 'http://my.website.com/myfile.raw';
  }
```

Comment: Does this really work? Normally the `src` attribute references a file in a known format such as png or jpg. I don't think browsers know about a "raw" format...

Comment: I think I misread the question when I answered that 4 years ago. Sorry.

Comment: I would maybe use this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data or even binary data with Websockets. Then you can do what ever you want with the data -- draw it to canvas etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<title>foo</title>
<script>
var canvas;

function draw(imgData) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var myImageData = ctx.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var ctxData = myImageData.data
    var iter = canvas.width * canvas.height * 4; //RGBA
    while(iter--){ctxData[iter] = imgData[iter];}
    ctx.putImageData(myImageData, 0, 0);
}

function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xmlHttp.responseType = "arraybuffer";   
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
            var arrayBuffer = xmlHttp.response
            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
            callback(byteArray);
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function tick(){
    httpGetAsync("http://127.0.0.1:8082/video", draw);
}

function loaded(){
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
}

window.setInterval(tick, 10000);
window.onload = loaded;

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>.................</div>
    <canvas id='canvas' width="320" Height="240" ></canvas>
    <div>.................</div>
</body>
```